# HMAC (SHA512/SHA256) for HTTP Requests on Python (Cryptocurrency)

Tags: python

This is not a specific code question, but rather a general question on how something would be done in Python. 
I am working on multiple cryptocurrency exchanges, and have to send HTTP requests to receive API data. For private user data and trade execution, I have to provide several parameters, almost all of which are generally unclear and one of which is a hash. The secret API key must somehow be hashed with hmac, in a specific order with the inclusion of other parameters and fields, to provide the correct parameter in the request. How on earth is this done correctly? I will provide sample instructions from an exchange.

## **Signing Requests**

POST requests have to be signed by authentication code. You have to use secret key for that, which you use to sign parameters with SHA512 algorithm. It is neccessary to send public key in header as API-Key and also hashed post message as API-Hash.

It is request execution unix timestamp. This value is compared with server time. If difference is bigger than 5 seconds - operation won’t be executed. It is important to have synchronized time with NTP public time server - in other case server time can differ a lot than time of request machine.

API call rate limit

The rate limit is 1 req / second.

API methods

List of methods, which you have to send in method parameter.

info - returns information about account balances

How do I sign this in Python and provide what they actually want correctly, and how do I apply those concepts to other exchanges? Please provide an explanation that will allow me to recreate what you have said/done in other situations.